# Best way to use HTML5 App Cache for caching OGG files for Firefox but MP3 for IE?

Tags: html, html5-audio, html5-appcache

Anyone have suggestions on how to best handle using App Cache when you have sets of assets used in one browser but not in another?

Example: OGG audio for Firefox and MP3 for IE. I can cache both types of files, but audio is huge and would store twice as many files as the browser can use.

My best thought is to create several different manifests. For example, one to load assets common to all browsers, and then a separate manifest for, say, MP3's, and load a page in an iframe that calls this manifest once I can determine on the client side that they're using IE. If however I find that they're using Firefox, I can load another page (with the attached OGG manifest) in the iframe.

Would this work or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm just using a nginx rewrite rule like this

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ Firefox) {
        rewrite ^.*\/(app.manifest)$ $scheme://$http_host/moz.manifest redirect;
    }
}
```

Most web servers will let you define similar rewrite rules. This is a good option because it's fast and doesn't require any further installation of software.

[This guy](http://grinninggecko.com/html5-offline-audio/) is checking which browser using PHP, but you could do this using any framework, preferably something fast like [Node](http://nodejs.org) or plain ruby Rack.